useState((state) => state.auth.user) returning empty
I'm using react redux for the signup and sign in of my react project. When a user signs in I want it to navigate to the profile page, or if there is an error, display the error. It works for the signup page but for some reason not for the sign in. The code is nearly identical so I don't understand why it's happening. I am a beginner to this sort of thing so I don't really know how to bug fix it. The issue I want to fix is that when you sign in, it reroutes you to the profile page and displays an error if there was one. At the moment it does neither on the sign in page, but for some reason does so on the sign up page. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me as it appears to work perfectly for the profile page.
main.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import "./index.css"
import axios from 'axios'
import { store } from './store/store.jsx'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, Route, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import SignupForm from './Components/signup'
import SigninForm from './Components/signin'
import RootLayout from './Components/root-layout'
import ErrorPage from './Components/error-page'
import ProfilePage from './Components/profile'

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements((
    <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<App />}></ Route>
      <Route path='/signup' element={<SignupForm />} ></Route>
      <Route path='/signin' element={<SigninForm />} ></Route>
      <Route path='*' element={<ErrorPage />}></Route>
      <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage />}></Route>
    </Route>
  )
))

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </Provider>
</React.StrictMode>,
)

store.jsx
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authSlice from './authSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authSlice
  }
})

authSlice.jsx
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const signup = createAsyncThunk('auth/signup', async({username, password}, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/signup', {username, password})
    return res.data
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.message)
  }
})

export const signin = createAsyncThunk('auth/signin', async({username, password}) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/signin', {username, password})
    return res.data
  } catch (err) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.response.data)
  }
})

const initialState = {
  user: '',
  isLoggedIn: false,
  loading: false,
  error:null
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: (state, action) => {
      state.user = ''
      state.isLoggedIn = false
      state.loading = false
      state.error = null
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signup.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.username
        state.isLoggedIn = true
        state.loading = false
        state.error = null
      })
      .addCase(signup.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true
      })
      .addCase(signup.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.isLoggedIn = false
        state.error = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(signin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.username
        state.isLoggedIn = true
        state.loading = false
        state.error = null
      })
      .addCase(signin.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true
      })
      .addCase(signin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.isLoggedIn = false
        state.error = action.payload
      })
  }
})

export const { logout } = authSlice.actions

export default authSlice.reducer

profile.jsx
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

export default function ProfilePage () {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user) //This useSelector works properly for some reason
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Profile</h3>
      {user ? <div>Hi, {user}!</div> : null}
    </div>
  )
}

signup.jsx
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { signup } from "../store/authSlice";

export default function SignupForm () {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user)
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.auth.error)
//These two useSelectors appear to not work when I console.log but the code still runs normally
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(signup({username, password}))
    .then((res) => {
      setPassword('')
      setUsername('')
    })
    console.log(user)
    console.log(error)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>Sign up</div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
          <input id="username" type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} minLength={1} maxLength={60}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} minLength={1}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        {error ? <p>{error}</p> : null}
        {user ? <Navigate to='/profile' replace={true} /> : null}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

signin.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { signin } from "../store/authSlice";

export default function SigninForm () {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user)
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.auth.error)
//These are the two not working ^
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(signin({username, password}))
    .then((res) => {
      setPassword('')
      setUsername('')
    })
    console.log(user)
    console.log(error)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>Sign in</div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
          <input id="username" type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} minLength={1} maxLength={60}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} minLength={1}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        {error ? <div>{error}</div> : null}
        {user ? <Navigate to='/profile' replace={true} /> : null}
//This is where the real issue is. These two ^ are not running even though it runs on the signup page
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

Sorry if this is a bit long. Any help would be appreciated
This is what the console.logs on the signin page return:
console
console.log showed me that the useSelectors were not running correctly. Do not really know how to try and fix them as the ones on the profile page run normally with the exact same code.

The initial state.auth.user value is "" and the initial state.auth.error value is null, so the console logs appear to agree. I don't see an issue here with your logs. What is the actual issue you are trying to fix, if there even is one? Please [edit] to clarify your question.

And just to clarify, if you are trying to console log these state values in the callbacks that (a) the callbacks have a closure over the selected state values from the time the callbacks are called and won't ever have a different value in the callback scope, and (b) the callbacks are synchronous so they're not going to wait for the Promise chains to resolve, so even if you could get new values in the callbacks, the code is logging before the state updates so couldn't possibly log them anyway.

It seems that the issue with the useSelector hook not updating the state on the signin page might be related to how the Redux state updates are being handled or rendered.

Do you know how I might be able to fix it so that it works properly?
